# An inequality of moments (bounding the probability of events which differ from all preceeding events)

Tags: probability

**Motivation**

The following question arises because I would like to lower bound the probability of a sequence of dependent events by the probability of a sequence of independent events. Given a probability distribution, I would like to lower bound the probability that the d+1<sup>st</sup> trial gives rise to a different outcome than the preceeding d trials, by the probability that we obtain two different outcomes in each of d *pairs* of trials.

**Problem**

Suppose that $\mathbf x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n, \ldots)$ is a probability distribution: that is, $x_j \geqslant 0$ for all $j$, and $\sum_{j\geqslant1} x_j = 1$. 
We may think of the coefficients $x_j$ not only as probabilities, but as random variables in their own right depending on $j$.
In particular, we may consider:
$$\begin{align*}
  \mathbb E\Bigl[ (1-x_j)^d \Bigr] \;&=\; \sum_{j \geqslant 1} x_j (1-x_j)^d \\[1ex]
  \mathbb E\Bigl[ 1 - x_j \Bigr]^{d} &=\; \left[ \sum_{j \geqslant 1} x_j (1-x_j) \right]^{d}
\end{align*}$$
Does $\mathbb E\Bigl[ (1-x_j)^d \Bigr] \geqslant\, \mathbb E\Bigl[ 1 - x_j \Bigr]^{d}$ for all $d \in \mathbb N$, and how does one show it? Does this sort of moment inequality hold in general, or at least in the case of $\mathbf x$ a probability distribution?

Comment: Obviously yes, due to the convexity of $u\mapsto u^d$ on $u\geqslant0$, for each positive integer $d$.

Comment: @Did: right you are; that's the sort of simple approach which was eluding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Did in the comments: the function $u \mapsto u^d$ is convex on the non-negative reals: for any $0 \leqslant p \leqslant 1$,
$$ pu_1^d + (1-p)u_2^d \;\geqslant\; \Bigl[pu_1 + (1-p)u_2^d\Bigr] ,$$
with equality iff $u_1 = u_2$; and (by induction) similarly for any discrete distribution. It follows immediately, that for any discretely distributed random variable $X$ over the non-negative reals,
$$ \mathbb E\Bigl[X^d\Bigr] \geqslant \mathbb E\bigl[X\bigr]^d. $$
Thus it follows in this particular case as well.

Comment: @Did: done. It seems that it doesn't pay to write very quickly.